# How to add authentication to start page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I wrote a console application (including webhost). This is a single page that contains the configuration of this program. The question is how routes should look like so that after opening the start page (for example index.html) authorization will works. I put all www contents to wwwroot folder and used:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Then I set up ConfigureServices with Basic Authentication.

[Authorize] works protect other routes.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/command")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
...
}
```

Im not using IISExpress so there is no launchUrl options.

Is there any "trick" ? something like `[Route("")]` ? Only simple user and password while opening e.g. localhost:5000.

By the way, maybe it would work with some template and :

```
 [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
         return View();
    }
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You can use page authorization with `AuthorizePage` method.

Comment: app.UseDefaultFiles removed, WithRazorPagesRoot path added then AddPageRoute and AuthorizePage... unfortunately 404. Probably missing additional configuration... Anyway thanks. it should work.

Comment: Try this in ConfigureServices method `services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Folder/file");
    });`

Comment: Doesn't work. First, I have to figure out how to Razor Pages works. still missing some configuration. I wrote this page outside VS with bootstrap and js, so there is no site mapping without UseDefaultFiles.

Comment: if i am understanding this right your application has only one c# file with no `UseMVC()`

Comment: @up Why ? I started from simple console application, then added all necessary files to run web host, including MVC to control all HTTP requests. Created website is used for configure this application (simple json file). All this works ok when I am using UseDefaultFiles(). Now I need to set Authentication on this main page.

Answer (score 1):

With UseDefaultFiles() it seems to be impossible.

But you can:

1. add `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();`(or create mvc routing by your own)
2. create razor page and copy content from yours page (my case)
3. use authentication type what you want and add in your controller:

`[Authorize]
[Route("/")] // when MvcWithDefaultRoute`

or use AuthorizePage (LIazar answer)